# Нужно ли корректировать знаки препинания в заданном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Обратила внимание на такое предложение:

***Если ты китаец, все, что ты делаешь, неправильно.*** [Ольга Андреева. Стланная стлана // «Русский репортер», 2014]

Мне кажется, что здесь не все корректно со знаками препинания, так как **пауза в СПП** четко не обозначена. Можно использовать указательное слово ТО, можно поставить тире. Но эти варианты мне тоже не очень нравятся.

**Да и нужна ли здесь пауза?** Иногда судишь о предложении, рассматривая его как нечто самостоятельное, но это не совсем правильно. Возможно, именно в таком виде оно хорошо вписывалось в контекст.

**А вы стали бы править это предложение?**

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В журналистике есть две плюс-минус тенденции:

1. Убирать слова, без которых не искажается смысл и не ломается синтаксис.
2. Везде, где можно, использовать запятую.

Но в вашем случае, мне кажется, оба правила применены чрезмерно строго, к тому же они часто друг другу противоречат: убирая слово, неплохо бы заменить его тире, например.

Что касается ошибок. В пунктуации их не вижу. А вот смысловая недостаточность некоторая имеется: *Всё, что делаешь, неправильно*.
Есть суть делания, а есть способ делания. Сравните: *Ты говоришь неправильно* -- это может значить и то, что говоришь неправильные вещи, и то, что говоришь неправильными словами, неправильно формулируешь или неправильно произносишь. В случае с *Всё, что делаешь, неправильно* менее заметно это "двоение", но оно есть. Поэтому что имела в виду автор, я так и не понял:

1. *Если ты китаец, то всё, за что ни возьмёшься, делаешь неправильным образом.*
   или
2. *Если ты китаец, то все поступки твои неправильны.*

**По итогу (моё мнение):** знаки можно не корректировать, а вот уточнить смысл было бы неплохо. Хотя он, возможно, ясен из контекста.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Меня интересовала именно пунктуация. Фраза  в такой записи звучит монотонно и невыразительно, хотя на письме все в пределах нормы.  В художественной речи я бы расценила это как недостаток. Но пробежав глазами статью, я изменила свое мнение. Показалось, что именно монотонность здесь как раз и нужна, она соответствует и содержанию высказывания,  и всем духу статьи. Это мысли тех людей, которые не привыкли думать, да и относиться к людям гуманно и уважительно они просто не могут.

Comment: Если у них есть хотя бы немного власти, они будут унижать своих подчиненных, тем более что эти люди – из другого мира.  Аккуратные, работящие, да  еще и успешные в своей работе. И дома у них всё бедно, но чистенько, так как они приучены к порядку. Вот этим они нехороши, этим раздражают. А приведенная фраза  – слоган, выражающий общее отношение к иным людям.То же самое касается двойственного смысла. Он действительно до конца непонятен, но это не так важно. То, что они хотели сказать, как раз соответствует форме сказанного: «неправильно» – в любом понимании. И вывод: вот как важен контекст.